# C leave array or variable in memory and access it on next execute of program

Tags: c, arrays, optimization

I am loading values from mysql into array and it takes around 20 minutes.
`dictionary` table got 3 columns word1 (INT), word2(INT), distance(double) 
word1 and word1 got values from 0 to 57999
some values of word2 are skipped because there are only 180 million rows (not 58000 * 58000)

```
int i;
double **word;
word=(double **) calloc(58000, sizeof(double *));
for(i=0;i<58000;i++)
    word[i]=(double *) calloc(58000, sizeof(double));

for(word1=0;word1<58000;word1++) {
        char query[600];
        sprintf(query, "SELECT word1, word2, distance from dictionary where word1='%d'", word1);
        mysql_query(con, query);
        result = mysql_store_result(con);
        while (row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) {
            double distance;
            word2 = atoi(row[1]);
            sscanf(row[2], "%lf", &distance);
            word[word1][word2] = distance; 
        }
        mysql_free_result(result);
}
```

This array takes 14 gb of ram and 7gb of virtual memory.
Now I can use this array for further calculations.

```
for(word1=0;word1<58000;word1++) {
    double result[58000];
    for(word2=0;word2<58000;word2++) {
        if(word1 != word2)
        for(i=0;i<58000;i++) {
            result[word1] += pow((word[word1][i] - word[word2][i]), 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Many of array values are 0
But I need array keys to identify which words I am comparing.
How can I improve this algorithm?
or
How do I load this array into memory once and reuse it next time I execute the program?

Comment: Just save it to a file, that's going to be leaps easier than setting up a persistent shared memory area.

Comment: These loops are allocating 25GB of memory.  Are you sure you're reading 58k items from the database 58k times during startup?

Comment: Do you ***really*** need that many `double`'s in memory at any given point? Oh, and PS: _don't cast the return value of `malloc` and `calloc`_. The better way to allocate memory is `double **word = malloc(58000 * sizeof *word);` and, in the loop: `word[i] = malloc(58000 * sizeof *word[i]);`. Anyway: I suspect that, if you were to actually show how you're using the `words` matrix for computation, and how you're querying the data, there's a good chance you can do with _massively_ less allocated memory

Comment: edited my answer and added more info

Answer (score 5):

In general you can't. Modern operating systems don't work that way.

The typical solution would be to split it into two programs, and have one persistent program expose the data through e.g. shared memory or something.

Failing that, of course you can just use a local on-disk file in some suitably raw format, it's going to load at some nice fraction of your I/O system's bandwidth if you write the loading code sensibly. Or memory-map the file, of course.

Also, as pointed out in comments, make sure you're not quadrupling the size of the problem space.

Comment: @undur_gongor Yup, I got it, that's my thought too. Not sure why the SQL server is so slow, but perhaps there's a slow network between them and it's too hard to duplicate the real database.